# Python user defined function written for ArcGIS Pro returns None when it should return an address?

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-pro, python-3

I am rewriting a 2.7 Python script for compatibility with ArcGIS Pro and organizing it with user defined functions so that I can debug portions of the script as I go. I am new to the process, but I thought it would be a good idea to pull the function out and test it alone. It's supposed to search a database and find an address location based on a SQL query. Right now the location is hardcoded for testing. When I run the script and print the selection variable, I get "None". Any suggestions or advice for debugging this?

```
import pdb
import arcpy
import os
import string
from io import StringIO
from io import BytesIO
import getpass 

def select_address():
    workspace = "G:\\Code Enforcement\\ACD Admin Operations\\GIS\\Operations\\BSC_Maps\\AutoLayerFiles.gdb"
    arcpy.env.workspace = workspace
    arcpy.env.overwritOutput = True
    location = '1900 McCall Rd'#arcpy.GetParameterAsText(0)
    expression = "FULL_STREET_NAME LIKE '" + location + "%'" #this is an SQL expression and can be modified as necessary
    aprx = arcpy.mp.ArcGISProject("G:\\Code Enforcement\\ACD Admin Operations\\GIS\\Operations\\BSC Maps\\BSC_Template_Auto_Generate_PRO_v1.aprx")
    for m in aprx.listMaps():
        #print(m)
        for lyr in m.listLayers():  
            #print(lyr)
            if lyr.name == "LOCATION.addresspoint":
                CoaAddresses = lyr
                #print(CoaAddresses)
                selection = arcpy.SelectLayerByAttribute_management(CoaAddresses,"NEW_SELECTION", expression)
                print(selection)
                for row in arcpy.SearchCursor(selection): #retrieve address of selected feature
                    selectedAddress = row.FULL_STREET_NAME
                    return(selectedAddress)

selection = select_address()
print(selection)
```

EDIT: I have tried applying the suggestions made in the comments and tried the following, but I still get None.

```
import pdb
import arcpy
import os
import string
from io import StringIO
from io import BytesIO
import getpass 
workspace = "G:\\Code Enforcement\\ACD Admin Operations\\GIS\\Operations\\BSC_Maps\\AutoLayerFiles.gdb"
arcpy.env.workspace = workspace
arcpy.env.overwritOutput = True
location = '7808 HART LN'#arcpy.GetParameterAsText(0)
aprx = arcpy.mp.ArcGISProject("G:\\Code Enforcement\\ACD Admin Operations\\GIS\\Operations\\BSC Maps\\BSC_Template_Auto_Generate_PRO_v1.aprx")


def select_address(address):

    expression = "FULL_STREET_NAME LIKE '" + address + "%'" #this is an SQL expression and can be modified as necessary
    for m in aprx.listMaps():
        #print(m)
        for lyr in m.listLayers():  
            if lyr.name == "LOCATION.addresspoint":
                CoaAddresses = lyr
            #print(lyr)
                with arcpy.da.SearchCursor(CoaAddresses, ['FULL_STREET_NAME'], where_clause=expression) as cursor:
                for row in cursor:
                    print(row[1])

selection = select_address(location)
print(selection)
```

Comment: Well you’re getting None because the searchcursor didn’t return anything. It probably found the map and layer otherwise it would have errored. So the problem Might be with your selection.  You could do the where clause on the search cursor instead of running the GP tool. That may simplify things.

Comment: Sorry, I'm not following you on that. How would I do the where clause on the search cursor? Isn't the search cursor the GP tool?

Comment: I tested the SQL within ArcPro and it does find an address so it's not a problem with the SQL expression.

Comment: See example #4 https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/analyze/arcpy-data-access/searchcursor-class.htm Also, if porting to Pro, perhaps consider updating to arcpy.da.SearchCursor for faster cursors....

Comment: Can this replace SelectLayersByAttribute_management?

Comment: you've got your selection variable set equal to the output from SelectLayerByAttribute, which is a GP tool result and not actually a layer, so it could be that your SearchCursor is returning None because it's searching the result. Perhaps try row in arcpy.SearchCursor(CoaAddress) and see if your results differ.

Comment: @MammothTarantula I tried  your change but still got None.

Comment: @KHibma One other question regarding the example: When referring to a local geodatabase we use 'c:/base/data.gdb/roads', but what if I'm referring to LOCATION.addresspoint, a layer in an oracle database that I have set up in the ArcPro project file? How do I refer to that?

Comment: I learned a lot from the comments. It turned out that the Location.addresspoint needed to be written Location.address_point. I have learned a lot about debugging by using print statements and else statements to narrow it down.

Comment: @AnthonyStokes Hmmm. One of those problems nobody here had much chance of solving as it’s data specific.  It’s still in your best interest to write up a short answer with what fixed your problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This chunk of code would produce an exception since your row index is out of range.

```
            with arcpy.da.SearchCursor(CoaAddresses, ['FULL_STREET_NAME'], where_clause=expression) as cursor:
            for row in cursor:
                print(row[1])
```

`row [1]` would produce the exception. You want `row [0]`. You also will want to `return` it.

`return (row [0])`

However since an exception isn't thrown the cursor is never initiated with records.

In your first code `selection` is a [Results object](https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/analyze/arcpy-classes/result.htm).

```
>>> selection = arcpy.SelectLayerByAttribute_management ("mains", "", "OBJECTID = 1")
>>> selection
<Result 'mains'>
```

Results objects can't be used as the input feature class in a cursor.

```
>>> with arcpy.SearchCursor (selection) as cursor:
...     for row in cursor:
...         print row.OBJECTID
...         
Runtime error 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: __exit__
>>>
```

Since you're never receiving an exception I suspect your layer isn't being found. With either instance make sure the following code returns `True` (a layer name is matched) at some point:

```
if lyr.name == "LOCATION.addresspoint":
```

---

Comment: This helped me narrow down the problem: "LOCATION.address_point" needed an underscore in it. In conjuction with @Emil Brundage's suggestions, I added print statements after each part of the function to narrow down the area where the problem is.